# How to force focus in text editor written with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-editor

I wrote a minimal text editor in python with the help of a youtube video.

I want to use it as a distraction-free writing app. The goal is to just boot up a pi and run this script directly. there are a few more features that I have planned, but for this here is my biggest challenge.

The problem right now is, that when I run the script I can't just start typing. I have to click into the text field or press the tab once to be able to write.

I want to open the script and be directly able to start typing. What do I need to add, so that the focus is directly in the text field from the start?

I tried hacking it by forcing a keypress at the beginning of the script, but I couldn't get it to work, and there must be a more elegant way to solve the problem.

Thanks, everyone for taking the time to read my question.

It's a short script, so I just added it in its entirety.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class Menubar:
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        font_specs = ("PibotoLt", 10)
        
        menubar = tk.Menu(parent.master, font=font_specs)
        menubar.configure(bg='black', fg='white')
        parent.master.config(menu=menubar)
        
        file_dropdown = tk.Menu(menubar, font=font_specs, tearoff=0)
        file_dropdown.configure(bg='black', fg='white')
        file_dropdown.add_command(label="New File",
                                  accelerator="Ctrl+N",
                                  command=parent.new_file)
        file_dropdown.add_command(label="Open File",
                                  accelerator="Ctrl+O",
                                  command=parent.open_file)
        file_dropdown.add_command(label="Save",
                                  accelerator="Ctrl+S",
                                  command=parent.save)
        file_dropdown.add_command(label="Save As",
                                  accelerator="Ctrl+Shift+S",
                                  command=parent.save_as)
        file_dropdown.add_separator()
        file_dropdown.add_command(label="Exit",
                                  command=parent.master.destroy)
        
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=file_dropdown)
        
        
class Statusbar:
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        
        font_specs = ("URW Gothic", 20, "bold")
        
        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        
        label = tk.Label(parent.textarea, textvariable=self.status, fg="yellow", bg="black", font=font_specs)
        
        label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH)
        
    def update_status(self, *args):
        if isinstance(args[0], bool):
            self.status.set("Your File Has Been Saved!")
        else:
            self.status.set("")
    

class PyWriter:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Untitled - Focalscribe")
        master.geometry("1200x700")
        master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
                
        font_specs = ("PibotoLt", 14)
        
        self.master = master
        self.filename = None
        
        self.textarea = tk.Text(master, font=font_specs)
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(master, command=self.textarea.yview)
        self.scroll.configure(bg='black')
        self.textarea.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set, bg='black', fg='white', insertbackground='white')
        self.textarea.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        
        self.menubar = Menubar(self)
        self.statusbar = Statusbar(self)
        
        self.bind_shortcuts()
    
    def set_window_title(self, name=None):
        if name:
            self.master.title(name + " - Focalscribe")
        else:
            self.master.title("Untitled - Focalscribe")
    
    def new_file(self, *args):
        self.textarea.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.filename = None
        self.set_window_title()
    
    def open_file(self, *args):
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            defaultextension=".txt",
            filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                       ("Text Files", "*.txt*"),
                       ("Markdown Documents", "*.md*"),
                       ("Python Scrips", "*.py*")])
        if self.filename:
            self.textarea.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            with open (self.filename, "r") as f:
                self.textarea.insert(1.0, f.read())
            self.set_window_title(self.filename)
    
    def save(self, *args):
        if self.filename:
            try:
                textarea_content = self.textarea.get(1.0, tk.END)
                with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
                    f.write(textarea_content)
                self.statusbar.update_status(True)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        else:
            self.save_as()
    
    def save_as(self, *args):
        try:
            new_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
                initialfile="Untitled.txt",
                defaultextension=".txt",
                filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*"),
                           ("Text Files", "*.txt*"),
                           ("Markdown Documents", "*.md*"),
                           ("Python Scrips", "*.py*")])
            textarea_content = self.textarea.get(1.0, tk.END)
            with open(new_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(textarea_content)
            self.filename = new_file
            self.set_window_title(self.filename)
            self.statusbar.update_status(True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    
    def bind_shortcuts(self):
        self.textarea.bind('<Control-n>', self.new_file)
        self.textarea.bind('<Control-o>', self.open_file)
        self.textarea.bind('<Control-s>', self.save)
        self.textarea.bind('<Control-S>', self.save_as)
        self.textarea.bind('<Key>', self.statusbar.update_status)

        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = tk.Tk()
    pw = PyWriter(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Call `self.textarea.focus_set()` at the end of `PyWriter.__init__()`.

Comment: thanks so much, seem so simple once you read it. a bit embarrassed now that I had to ask.

Comment: That's how a lot of programming solutions seem once you figure them out :-). Feel free to write and accept an answer if you like, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.